# Java runtime error: java.lang.ClassCastException: main.Scrapper$aktie cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Tags: java, runtime-error

I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: main.Scrapper$aktie cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

when I'm trying to create a class that I have defined myself. What can I do to fix it? The data is always the right type, so that's not the problem, I have tried to parse them in to variables before putting them in the class but I still get the same error

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Scrapper extends Thread {

    private String address;
    private ArrayList<String> name;
    private ArrayList<String> ranInfo;
    public PriorityQueue<aktie> aktier;
    public boolean runner;

    public Scrapper(String webAddress) {
        address = webAddress;
        runner = true;
    }

    public class aktie {
        public aktie(String aktieNamn, float senaste, float sIP, float eÅP, int totBV, float esK, float dA, int aÄ, String börsNamn) {
            this.namn = aktieNamn;
            this.senaste = senaste;
            this.skillnadIProcent = sIP;
            this.ettÅrProcent = eÅP;
            this.totalBörsvärde = totBV;
            this.enskildKostnad = esK;
            this.direktAvkastning = dA;
            this.antalÄgare = aÄ;
            this.vilkenBörs = börsNamn;
            this.newAktie = true;
        }
        public String namn;
        public float senaste;
        public float skillnadIProcent;
        public float ettÅrProcent;
        public int totalBörsvärde;
        public float enskildKostnad;
        public float direktAvkastning;
        public int antalÄgare;
        public String vilkenBörs;
        public boolean newAktie;

        public boolean equal(aktie input) {
            if  (input.namn.equals(namn) && 
                input.senaste == senaste && 
                input.skillnadIProcent == skillnadIProcent &&
                input.ettÅrProcent == ettÅrProcent &&
                input.totalBörsvärde == totalBörsvärde &&
                input.enskildKostnad == enskildKostnad &&
                input.direktAvkastning == direktAvkastning &&
                input.antalÄgare == antalÄgare &&
                input.vilkenBörs.equals(vilkenBörs)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        name = new ArrayList<String>();
        ranInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
        aktier = new PriorityQueue<aktie>();
        while(runner) {
            Document namnSidan = null;
            Document sidan = null;
            try {
                namnSidan = Jsoup.connect(address).get();
                sidan = Jsoup.connect(address).get();
            } catch(Throwable t) {
                Start.log(t.toString());
            }
            Elements nmList = namnSidan.select("td");//td, table
            for(int i = 0; i < nmList.size(); i++) {
                String[] temper = nmList.get(i).toString().split("</span>");
                if(temper.length > 1) {
                    String[] tm = temper[1].split(" </a>");
                    if(!tm[0].equals(" </td>") && tm.length > 1) {
                        name.add(tm[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
            Elements values = sidan.select("td");
            for(int i = 1; i < values.size(); i++) {
                String[] splitted = values.get(i).toString().split(" </span>");
                String[] fixed = splitted[0].split(">");
                if(!fixed[fixed.length-1].equals("</td") && !fixed[fixed.length-1].equals(" </td")) {
                    String rätt = fixed[fixed.length-1].substring(1, fixed[fixed.length-1].length());
                    String[] pars = rätt.split("&nbsp;");
                    if(1 < pars.length) {
                        ranInfo.add(pars[0] + pars[1]);
                    } else if(rätt.equals("-")) {
                        ranInfo.add("0.0f");
                    } else {
                        String[] cutt = rätt.split(",");
                        if(cutt.length > 1) {
                            ranInfo.add(cutt[0] + "." + cutt[1]);
                        } else {
                            ranInfo.add(rätt);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            int counter = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
                aktier.add(new aktie( //<- error happens here
                        name.get(i), 
                        Float.parseFloat(ranInfo.get(counter++)), 
                        Float.parseFloat(ranInfo.get(counter++)), 
                        Float.parseFloat(ranInfo.get(counter++)), 
                        Integer.parseInt(ranInfo.get(counter++)), 
                        Float.parseFloat(ranInfo.get(counter++)), 
                        Float.parseFloat(ranInfo.get(counter++)), 
                        Integer.parseInt(ranInfo.get(counter++)), 
                        ranInfo.get(counter++)));
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(120000);
            } catch(Throwable t) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should not implement something like "public boolean equal(aktie input)" but override the existing equals(Object obj) method.

Second, you need to implement comparable on aktie, since priorityQueue  expects a Comparable implementation, or, if you do not want to do that, you have to implement a Comparator and give it to your PriorityQueue.

Third, if you plan on working with money values, DO NOT use float or double since they are just APPROXIMATED values!!! Either use int, long or BigDecimal.

Lastly, if you seek help from others, make it a bit more obvious for them by pointing out where the exception is thrown right in your description.

Comment: Thx for the help, can i solve the problem by just checking the values on by one in the code instead of implementing a method for it? why would i not use floats when the input from the webbsite is floats? And yes i will try to make it better next time, its my second question so still tring to learn how to do it properly

Comment: Whatever website you are refering to, im sure you get your data via some  web API, and your data contains values like "1.23" or "253.24" or whatever, these are NOT floats or doubles because of decimal places, and if you assign them to double or float you will loose precision, e.g. a float of 1 is not exactly 1 but more rather 0.9999999999. Obviously this will cause huge problems when working with monetary values.

Comment: Considering implementation of compare method, what exactly do you want to achieve by putting your elements to a PriorityQueue, instead of a regular Queue, which would not require a Comparator or Comparables?

Comment: Well thats preatty weird, didnt know floats where "broken". Im just using proirityqueue instead of queue, my teacher (not a very good one) have learned us to us priorityqueue but havent shown us the queue, used it instead of a list so i could poll the first element when i used it. And im not using a webb api, im doing webscraping on a website that got the info

Comment: But even if the float are as u say, if its 0,000.....1 wrong. Isnt that better then to make 1,48264 to 1?

Comment: float and double are not broken, they are meant for scientific calculatations where approximations are ok, and when you use int instead of float you obviously dont round from 1,34$ to 1$, but represtent it as 134 cents. Then again you dont have to do that, just use BigDecimal which is 100% accurate. And obviously you dont need the priority queue so just use the a standard queue where you dont need to compare your elements.

Comment: And then please accept the answer after you got way more help than your problem acctually required.